# Elasticsearch: CircuitBreakingException on Aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Amazon Elasticsearch Service (Elasticsearch 1.5)

When we do simple `terms` aggregations on our index, we always receive a `CircuitBreakingException` (`[FIELDDATA] Data too large` .. `data for [colors] would be larger than limit of [639015321/609.4mb]]`)

```
"aggs": {
    "colors": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "colors"
       }
    }
}
```

`colors` is expected to contain < 256 values, so the size would be quite limited. The same error occurs when the aggregation is done on a price field with 4 ranges, for a larger index (>10M items) but also for smaller (<10K items).

The fields that are aggregated upon are all integers/long, no strings.

I tried to limit the aggregation by adding a `size`. But that did not help either.

Is there something I do wrong with the aggregation? And if not, is there any work-around for this?

Comment: Increasing the heapsize for "fielddata" worked: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#circuit-breaker. Question: Is this the way to solve this problem? I increased "indices.breaker.fielddata.limit" to "80%".

Comment: Yes, that's [the way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811046/fielddata-data-is-too-large)

Comment: Thanks, haven't seen this question. I guess, we will have to increase the Amazon Instance size as we get into the same error again just with a larger field size (`limit of [745517875/710.9mb]`).

Comment: Increasing memory is indeed the next step if the previous one doesn't help. Other than that, I would use doc values instead to offload a much as possible from fielddata.