# Elasticsearch returns an error of exceeding the limit fielddata

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a problem with sorting namely, sorting work but only for price field. When I try to sort by start_date, end_date, uid, cat title get the message about exceeding the limit:

```
Data too large, the date for [ "name of field here"] would be larger than the limit of [19798897459 / 18.4gb]]
```

I do not know why this is happening code looks correct sample query for elastica looks like this:

Mapping:

```
"auctions": {
                "_all": { "enabled": false }, 
                "properties": {
                    "cat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "curr": { "index": "not_analyzed",  "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "end_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "price": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "start_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "tcat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                    "title": { "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                    "uid": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }
                }
            },
```

Request:

### **/search?uids=335,547&title=Karta&orderBy=uid&orderDir=asc**

Method:

```
private NativeSearchQueryBuilder getSearchQuery(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));
        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many uids
        if (searchParams.getUids() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getItemId() != null || searchParams.getTitle() != null) {
                Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUids().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                    filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("uid", v)));
                });
            } else {
                for (String user : searchParams.getUids().split(",")) {
                    boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(user).field("uid"));
                }
            }
        }
        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCategories() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategories().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }

        if (searchParams.getItemId() != null) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getItemId()).field("_id"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {

            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        if (searchParams.getOrderBy() != null && searchParams.getOrderDir() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getOrderDir().toLowerCase().equals("asc")) {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.ASC));
            } else {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.DESC));
            }
        }

        if (pageable != null) {
            searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        }
        System.out.println(searchQuery.build().getQuery());
        System.out.println(searchQuery.build().getFilter());
        System.out.println(searchQuery.build().getSort());
        return searchQuery;
    }
```

**System.out.println(searchQuery.build().getQuery());**

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "query_string": {
        "query", "card"
        "fields": [ "title"]
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**System.out.println (searchQuery.build().getFilter());**

```
{
  "and" {
    "filters": [{
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "terms": {
            "uid" [ "335", "547"]
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**System.out.println(searchQuery.build().getSort());**

```
null
```

Any ideas what might cause this exception?

I should add that I've tried these solutions:

[FIELDDATA Data is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811046/fielddata-data-is-too-large)

But the effect was even worse, then no query did not work as quickly.

For any help I will be extremely grateful!

/_stats/fielddata?fields=*

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 19466671904,
                "evictions": 0,
                "fields": {
                    "_id": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                    },
                    "cat": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 3235221240
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 16231450664
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 19466671904,
                "evictions": 0,
                "fields": {
                    "_id": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                    },
                    "cat": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 3235221240
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "memory_size_in_bytes": 16231450664
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "indices": {
        "allek": {
            "primaries": {
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 19466671904,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "fields": {
                        "_id": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                        },
                        "cat": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 3235221240
                        },
                        "title": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 16231450664
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 19466671904,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "fields": {
                        "_id": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                        },
                        "cat": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 3235221240
                        },
                        "title": {
                            "memory_size_in_bytes": 16231450664
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

I solved the problem as follows:

After discernment, it turned out that I'm using version 1.7. The documentation I found information that doc_values must be set in the mapping to true if you want to sort or aggregate. Fields strings need to add another field multifield.

So after a map change to something more or less like this:

```
{
  "_all": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "cat": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "curr": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": true,
      "type": "string",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "end_date": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "price": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "start_date": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "tcat": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "title": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "doc_values": true
        }
      }
    },
    "uid": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    }
  }
}
```

Sorting work, but slowed down the whole sysytem search, I will say that much, although the documentation is from about 10-20%.

You should also remember to reindex data!

Thanks!

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811046/fielddata-data-is-too-large/30814856#30814856

Comment: Hey, I try it and it`s in my question body look " FIELDDATA Data is too large " :)