# Elastic search Circuitbreak exception

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

We are getting the below exception in elasticsearch.

> Exception in Candidate retrieval from ES Failed to execute phase
>   [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[b1qoNHn7R-q9fRXph2I_8A][global-match-748_sz][0]:
>   RemoteTransportException[[dbqlgmtch07.us.dnb.com][158.151.157.232:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query+fetch]]];
>   nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for
>   [] would be larger than limit of [7314708889/6.8gb]];

Could some one help us on this ?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811046/fielddata-data-is-too-large/30814856#30814856

Comment: we have already this but we still we are gettting the same error

Comment: You might need to tune the percentage, 75% might not work for you.

Comment: Now is the issue is fixed thanks

Comment: Awesome, maybe you should post an answer describing what you did so as to help others with the same problem.