# Elasticsearch: Data too large, data for [_uid] would be larger than limit of [1267571097/1.1gb]]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to query elasticsearch to retrieve some document that got the keyword `#test` in their documents. The `all_hateful_ids` is a list of id. When I send this query to elasticsearch I've got the following error.

```
query = {
  "size": 100,
  "_source": "text",
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {"terms": {"id_tweet_creator": all_hateful_ids}}
            ],
          "should": [
            {"match": {
              "text": "#test"
            }}
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {"exists": {"field": "retweeted_status"}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: CircuitBreakingException[[fielddata] Data too large, data for [_uid] would be larger than limit of [1267571097/1.1gb]]')
```

The problem is that if I remove the filter key, then my query is answered. Why? A filter should reduce the amount of data, so there is no way than my elasticsearch doesn't have enough memory to process without the filter field but get a memory problem with the filter. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How many IDs do you have inside the `all_hateful_ids` array?

Comment: 500-600, I try to reduce the number to 20 but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811046/fielddata-data-is-too-large/30814856#30814856

Comment: How many documents do you have in this index? Does the index have multiple types? Are you querying one of the types or all of them?

Comment: @Val I did this it worked. Can you you write it as an answer to validate it

Comment: @mel Since an answer exists already, I suggest that you upvote it if it helped you ;-)